# Response.Redirect passes the ISAPI_Rewrite engine

Tags: asp.net, redirect, response, isapi

*I use ISAPI_Rewrite v2

Hi,
So I implement ISAPI_Rewrite on my site. 
Now i put on my pages a Response.Redirect 
But as it seems the redirect passes the ISAPI engine.. 
i.e. I see the new url but the rule doesnt apply.

for example i enter this: 
example.com/SomePage.aspx

in SomePage.aspx.cs - PageLoad function theres:

Response.Redirect("/Page");

So I get redirected to example.com/Page 
But it says to me "This link appears to be broken"

on httpd.ini I have this rule

RewriteRule ^/Page$ /Page.aspx [L]

My guess is that the Response.Redirect doesnt go through 
the ISAPI_Rewrite...

How can I fix this??

Thanks

=====
edit:

solved, the hebrew chars was the problem, you need to encode them first.

Answer (score 0):

if you do response.redirect the whole page life cycle is working. All the modules are called as usual. So maybe the rewrite module does not get called?
Did you put some breakpoints in the module so that you know if it gets called or not?
have you set up your module somewhere in your webapp?

Comment: solved, the hebrew chars was the problem, you need to encode them first.